# What is causing Segmentation error to occur?

Tags: c, cs50, vigenere

On running as above the program shows segmentation fault. Why is it so?
The program is for vigenere cipher . What I am doing is storing the key in a string and then storing the integer value of key as we used to do in caesar cipher and then implementing vigenere cipher but somehow it shows segmentation fault if I compile it and then using ./a.out bacon. I am not able to figure out why is it happening(what is causing segmentation fault).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if((argc==2)&&(isalpha(argv[1])))
    {
        string k;
        k=argv[1];
        string p = GetString();
        int lenkey=strlen(k);
        int lenp=strlen(p);
        string c="hello";
        char temp;

        //change key to lowercase and store the shift value as in caesar
        for(int i=0;i<lenkey;i++)
        {
            temp=tolower(k[i]);
            k[i]=temp -'a';

        }
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<lenp;i++)
        {
            //i is for plaintext j is for key
            if(isalpha(p[i]))
            {
                j++;
                if(j==(lenkey-1)) j=0;//reset the key if end is reached
                if(isupper(p[i]))
                {
                    p[i] = p[i]-'A';
                    c[i] = (p[i]+k[j])%26;
                    c[i] = c[i]+'A';
                }
                if(islower(p[i]))
                {
                    p[i] = p[i]-'a';
                    c[i] = (p[i]+k[j])%26;
                    c[i] = c[i]+'a';
                }
            }
            else
                c[i]=p[i];
        }

        printf("%s\n",c);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {   printf("what?\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `string`? I assume that's in `cs50.h` since it doesn't exist in any of the other (standard) headers. so your code could, quite literally, be doing *anything!*

Comment: `string` is `typedef char* string` which comes in `cs50` header file

Comment: Okay, so what does `GetString()` give you?

Comment: `GetString()` takes input from user and stores in the string

Answer (score 1):

About `atoi`: "*returns the int value produced by interpreting the input characters as a number. The return value is 0  if the input cannot be converted to a value of that type.*"

So your `atoi(c) -'a'` will fail and produce a negative number (`c` being the string "hello" which cannot be interpreted as a number).

Probably you mean:

```
        temp=tolower(k[i]);
        k[i]=temp -'a';
```

---

The following may also be an error:

```
    for(int i=0;i<lenp;i++) {
        ...
        c[i] = c[i]+'A';
```

because `i<lenp` but it must be < than the length of `c`, which is 5.

Besides that, `char *c="hello"` makes c a constant string (literal) and you cannot modify a literal. Hence: seg fault. Use:

```
char c[]="hello";
```

(everybody, including teachers: Drop that `string`! it confuses everybody!)

Comment: Use a debugger to check _where_ it crashes. There may be more errors than only this one.